# Remove a character in while matching in regex

Tags: regex

I need to match a particular string with a space in between and the resulting matching group should have the space removed.

For example,
If the string is "Action 50", the regex should be such that the matching group should match the string "Action 50" but the returned value should be "Action50".

Is there any operator in regex to do this?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You have to match the string, then process them later. It needs 2 step. What's the language, btw?

Comment: why do you want to use regular expressions? If your (unspecified) language provides a way of replacing one substring (" ") with another (""), you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which software you use for regex but :

Source Regex : `"^(.*) (.*)$"` 
Dest Regex :  `"\1\2"`

In most regex tools, you can use parenthesis for put strings in memory.
After you can get them with `"\x"`, where x is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the expected result that you need:

```
grep -o "search pattern" filename | sed -e 's/ //'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with two groups and afterwards concatenate both groups:

```
(Action)\s+(\d+)
```

and then use groups 1 and 2.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> 'bdfskildhfAction 50sdlfhjsf' -match '(Action)\s+(\d+)'; $Matches[1] + $Matches[2]
True
Action50
```